# Use Raspberry Pi to monitor traffic on local network through a specific port

Tags: networking, media-server, port-forwarding

Is there a way to have a Raspberry Pi Model 3B+ monitor traffic on the local network through a specific port?

I am running Plex on another machine on the network and have my router port forwarding to that machine port 32400 (the default Plex port). I like to keep my computer asleep when not in use, and I want to have the Raspberry Pi wake it whenever a request is sent to that port on the Plex machine.

I can take care of the waking and all that, I just need to know how to trigger the Pi to wake Plex.

**UPDATE** with info from a comment:
The Pi will always be on and is connected to the router's wifi network and connected to the Plex machine via ethernet cable. I'm not sure if the protocol uses a redirect. The frontend of Plex is hosted on their own servers elsewhere, whereas the actual media is hosted on my machine, so the end user will be able to access the Plex frontend no matter what, but will only be able to view my library once my machine is awake.

**UPDATE**
My router does not have a WOL feature, nor can I introduce any kind of scripting.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116844/discussion-on-question-by-mattr-use-raspberry-pi-to-monitor-traffic-on-local-net).